# PHP $_SESSION variable in CONSTANT

Tags: php, session, constants

I am trying to define a session variable as constant ...

```
define("MY_VAR", $_SESSION['variable_name']);
```

I start the **session** before accessing this constant

However, when I try to change the value of the variable ...

```
MY_VAR = "xyz"
```

... I get following message

```
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in"
```

I am not sure what's happening here. It would be great if someone could shed some light on this.

**Note:** Instead, if I use `$_SESSION['variable_name']` at all places where I used `MY_VAR`, the code works fine

Comment: You cannot *assign to constants.* Constants are, well, **constant.** If they were mutable they'd be *variables.*

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use a constant as a reference to another variable - that's not what they're for at all.

Comment: Thanks iainn ! That is the reply/answer that I was looking for ... is there anything you would recommend to use as "reference" ...

The thing I can think of is just creating a variable to store the new value and updating the session variable at the end ... but I was looking for a "reference" approach rather so that I don't have to mention the session variable in every page.

Comment: You can assign a reference variable in PHP using `=&` - [have a read through the docs here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php). Constants are entirely separate from this.

Comment: @iainn : Thanks a lot! I will go through it.

Comment: @iainn: Just an update ... I read through the link you shared. I think that won't solve my purpose, as it seems that it won't update my session variable value directly. I think I should simply write a function to address this. Thanks so much for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of constants is they are **constant**.

Once set you can't change them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong but my understanding is that the **constant**'s value is the name of the SESSION variable; variable's value can be changed by referring to the constant.

So for example ...

let's say, *$_SESSION['variable_name'] = "abc"*

I create a constant *define("MY_CONSTANT", $_SESSION['variable_name']);*

and then I change *MY_CONSTANT="xyz";*

wouldn't that make *$_SESSION['variable_name'] = "xyz"*?

Comment: @DesV Constants can not be changed. `As the name suggests, that value cannot change during the execution of the script` -http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

Comment: Thanks! so I got that I was using it in a wrong way. But "iainn" (above) understood what I was trying to do and looking for...